# Organize DOM when appending dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom, append

I have 2 `input` and one p `element`.

I append a wrapper div only input elements but when i append element element's order changing.

**I mean, as you can see the first one is `p` element. But if you remove javascript codes, p elements is in second line**.

How can we fix this?

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sz4kkc8e/)**

```js
var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  if (input[i].type == "text") {

    // Create wrapper div
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.appendChild(input[i]);

  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="first" />
<p>Lorem</p>
<input type="text" value="third" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're basically trying to wrap each `<input>` in a `<div>` without changing its position in the DOM. As you've discovered, `appendChild` does what it says on the tin, i.e. adds the element to the end of the parent's children.

To put an element somewhere other than the end, use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) or [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild). The latter would look like this:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  var input = inputs[i];
  if (input.type === 'text') {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    input.parentElement.replaceChild(div, input);
    div.appendChild(input);
  }
}
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="first" />
<p>Lorem</p>
<input type="text" value="third" />
```

Or, more succinctly:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'), input => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  input.parentElement.replaceChild(div, input);
  div.appendChild(input);
});
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="first" />
<p>Lorem</p>
<input type="text" value="third" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceChild` to replace the input with the new div. That way the order is preserved:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
document.body.replaceChild(input[i], div);
div.appendChild(input[i]);
```